# Could not create the Java virtual machine error?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using Apache tomcat. I am running Tomcat through cmd.exe. I have been able to deploy a "Hello World" webapp with no problems. However, I have tried to run the servlet 'HelloServlet.java' by typing:
"C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC3\webapps\hello\WEB-INF\java -d classes src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java"
Or
"C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC3\webapps\hello\WEB-INF\classes java HelloServlet.java"

but I always get the error
"Unrecognized option: -d
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit"

If I try:
"C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC3\webapps\hello\WEB-INF\javac -d classes src\mypkg\HelloServlet.java"

then I get the message " 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file "

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple problems in your approach:

1. First you need to learn about Servlets. Servlets do not run as a standalone program
2. Tomcat is a container for web application deployment. Web applications need to be organized in a proper format. Web apps can contain servlets.
3. Tomcat is not used for compiling servlets/java programs
4. Follow a simple tutorial to learn about servlets and tomcat

Comment: I get the same error " 'javac' is not recognized..." even though I've followed numerous tutorials on servlets, such as the following http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html ; http://cs.calstatela.edu/~abbott/Courses/CS_320b/Running%20a%20Servlet%20under%20Tomcat.html ; http://mithujava.com/tag/helloservlet-prorgram/